# How to launch openbios from Qemu

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, bootloader, bios

Good day,

So I am following this **coreboot v3 + OpenBIOS** tutorial [Here](https://www.coreboot.org/QEMU) .

In the instructions I have the following...

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
wget http://www.coreboot.org/images/9/9d/Qemu_coreboot_openbios.zip
wget http://www.coreboot.org/images/0/0d/Vgabios-cirrus.zip
unzip Qemu_coreboot_openbios.zip
unzip Vgabios-cirrus.zip
mv qemu_coreboot_openbios.bin bios.bin
cd ..
qemu -L foo -hda /dev/zero -serial stdio
```

I noticed that qemu has been replace or is implemented with qemu-system.

**command I am running**

```
qemu-x86_64 -L foo -hda /dev/zero -serial stdio
```

When I run the command, I see just qemu run it's typical and not find a disk.(which I expect since the disk switch points to /dev/zero) but none of the payloads run as I would expect from the tutorial.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Should I use a different version of qemu?
Should I create a dummy disk for this?

Qemu seems to be ignoring the files in the foo directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples are not up to date, as you have noticed by the renaming of qemu to qemu-system-x86_64.

I managed to get the examples to work using only the cirrus video card, and by renaming the outputs of the zips (bin - bios files to bios-256k.bin). I did this because by adding the -L option I specify the bios location and qemu will look for a file called bios-256k.bin as the bios. The command to run the bios with cirrus (all done while in the foo directory) was

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -L . -vga cirrus  -serial stdio
```

Both machine types pc and q35 worked.

Comment: Wow. Ok , I will check this out this weekend.

Comment: I found this page when I was trying to get it to work. The -bios option on qemu might be your friend too. Cheers.

Comment: Ok I had to rename the bios to the bios-256k.bin and launched it and it worked.